# Socket.io 2.x with Sails

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

Currently sails.io is using socket.io 1.7.1. It is not going to change in sails 1.0. So I was planning to use socket.io 2.0 using the socket.io package instead of relying on sails real-time layer. According to socket.io documentation, it is quite easy to implement in express as follows:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

How can we write the same socket.io 2.0 implementation in sails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying Express server used in a Sails 1.0 app is exposed as `sails.hooks.http.server`.  So you can piggyback on top of that in your app's `config/bootstrap.js` file:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (done) {

  var io = require('socket.io')(sails.hooks.http.server);
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
  });

}
```

You'll also need to turn off the default `sockets` and `pubsub` hooks, in your `.sailsrc` file:

```
"hooks": {
  "sockets": false,
  "pubsub": false
}
```

This also has the benefit of freeing up the `sails.io` global, so you can re-use that for your own implementation.

Comment: if I have an implementation in Bootstrap, How do you suggest to export socket for controllers to emit the message? Should I assign it to sails.config.global or `sails.socket = socket` when connection is established?